# Argument 1 passed to Tymon\JWTAuth\Blacklist::__construct() must be an instance of Tymon\JWTAuth\Contracts\Providers\Storage, null given

Tags: laravel, jwt

I would like to ask for help on this as I've been trying to solve this issue in hours now.

I don't know what's wrong on my end but it keeps on prompting

> Argument 1 passed to Tymon\JWTAuth\Blacklist::__construct() must be an instance of Tymon\JWTAuth\Contracts\Providers\Storage, null given, called in /var/www/mmstraining/vendor/tymon/jwt-auth/src/Providers/AbstractServiceProvider.php on line 288 in file /var/www/mmstraining/vendor/tymon/jwt-auth/src/Blacklist.php on line 54

As per checking, Storage class is null though the interface is existing. I have no idea what's causing the error. Maybe some of you have encountered the issue. Appreciate the help!

Thanks

Answer (score 8):

I tried everything I could to fix this, and ended up finally getting somewhere after running php artisan config:clear

That was it. Hope this helps others.

Comment: I am not sure I understood how this helps to solve the problem. Could you please give some more details about how is this command is related to the exception in the question?

Comment: Just running php artisan config:clear made the error disapear (although there might be other errors).

Answer (score 0):

There's a config file associated with that package. You may have to run `php artisan vendor:publish` to copy the file to your `app` folder, but in it is a line to (de)activate the Blacklist functionality entirely, as well as define a Storage driver for it to use. Looks like by default it uses an out-of-the-box one that taps into Laravel's Cache handler, so I'm not sure why it would be giving you trouble, but I'd start by verifying that's set up properly.

Comment: Thank you for answering. I tried republishing the config by running `php artisan vendor:publish` but error still persists. I followed my setup thoroughly based on this tutorial [link](https://medium.com/@Gbxnga/token-based-authentication-with-react-and-laravel-restful-api-83f16581e85).